# Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected refinerycms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, production, refinerycms

Refinerycms showing error in production mode

Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected

In local i have no problem

Full error details:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-21 11:54:49 +0530
Processing by Refinery::PagesController#home as HTML
Parameters: {"locale"=>:en}
Rendered public/404.html (0.1ms)
Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 13ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

Please suggest me a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi ,
I solved the issue,
The issue is i had no home page it seems, 
so i created a page and in advanced option i forwarded the page to / 
This solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue,
The issue is i had no home page it seems, 
so i created a page and in advanced option i forwarded the page to / 
This solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

same problem for different page,(localhost:3000/users/sign_in)

devise not mentioned(devise_for :users .....) in routes.rb file, so refinery showed this error

```
 Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-03 16:09:23 +0530
 Processing by Refinery::PagesController#show as HTML
 Parameters: {"path"=>"users/sign_in", "locale"=>:en}
 Refinery::Role Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" WHERE    "refinery_roles"."title" = 'Refinery' LIMIT 1
 Refinery::User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_users"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" WHERE "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" = 1
 Refinery::Page Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages" INNER JOIN "refinery_page_translations" ON "refinery_page_translations"."refinery_page_id" = "refinery_pages"."id" WHERE "refinery_page_translations"."locale" IN ('en') AND "refinery_page_translations"."slug" = 'users' AND "refinery_pages"."parent_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
 Refinery::Page Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages" WHERE "refinery_pages"."menu_match" = '^/404$' LIMIT 1
 Rendered public/404.html (0.1ms)
 Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
 Completed 404 Not Found in 25ms (Views: 8.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.1ms)
```

adding devise routes solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error suddenly after changing databases. I found this advice on the [Getting Started](http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started-with-refinery#switching-to-your-front-end) page:

> If you get a 404 error on the homepage, try running the `rake db:seed` and then restarting the server.

That resolved the lack of a home page in my case.